# Python apply several actions to multiple files in a folder

Tags: python, pandas

I have 1 sample dataset in an excel file to which i've applied some of the following example commands using Pandas:

```
df = df.T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.loc[3:8]
df = df['col2', 'col8', 'col10']
```

(these are just examples)

The aim is to apply the same steps but to several thousand of these files saved in a directory with random file names and then append them all together.

Please could you help guide on this?

I was trying to use the glob commands from some other stack overflow posts but not getting anywhere.

For merging:

```
frame = [df1, df2, df3] etc
dataframe = pd.DataFrame()

for df in frame:
dataframe = dataframe.append(df)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pathlib.path to iterate through your directory and perform your dataframe operations one by one as in code below:

```
from pathlib import Path

_dir = Path.cwd() # or Path('your/directory')
files = _dir.glob('*.xlsx')

final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in files:
    df = pd.read_excel(i)
    # your df operations
    final_df = pd.concat([final_df, df])

final_df
```